# Tools to create HelpBooks for Mac Apps

Tags: cocoa, macos, apple-help

Bill van Hecke's [Helpify](http://www.omnigroup.com/blog/entry/Helpify_1.5_Help_Us_Help_You_Help_Users/) is a nice tool to convert OmniOutliner documents to Apple [HelpBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH204-CHDIDJFE).

I wonder, if other tools are available to create HelpBooks, e.g. a CMS with pre-configured templates.

Do you know of any HelpBook generator tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [Help Generator](http://code.google.com/p/helpgenerator/), which parses a simple XML format and creates help books that look very similar to Apple's (at least in the Leopard/Snow Leopard timeframe).